# Record not getting filtered using like clause

Tags: sql-server

Using below query to filter records:

```
select * from SearchRecord where searchkeyword1  like  '[%'
```

Tried this also

```
select * from SearchRecord where searchkeyword1  like  '%[%'
```

Records in table contain these values (as per below i need last 2 records, why this simple like won't filter records)

```
"Affiliate" means
"Agent's Rate of Exchange" means
["Aggregate Total Commitments" means
["Agreed Security Principles" means
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your search pattern contains a `wildcard character` `[`,
you should enclose it in brackets or use `ESCAPE character` like this:

```
declare @SearchRecord table (searchkeyword1 varchar(100));
insert into @SearchRecord values
('"Affiliate" means'),
('"Agent''''s Rate of Exchange" means'),
('["Aggregate Total Commitments" means'),
('["Agreed Security Principles" means');

select * 
from @SearchRecord 
where searchkeyword1  like  '![%' ESCAPE '!';

select * 
from @SearchRecord 
where searchkeyword1  like  '[[]%';
```

All this is described here:
[LIKE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ESCAPE '<some char>'` to tell SQL how to interpret the character after .

```
SELECT * FROM SearchRecord WHERE SearchKeyword LIKE '%\[%' ESCAPE '\';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=43cad34d58125d85cf8d134543e6a4a0)*